# What are the benefits of porting 32-bit iOS apps to 64-bits?

Tags: ios, arm64

If I have an existing tested 32-bit app code base, is porting to 64-bit worth the effort? What are the benefits? It will obviously take more memory at run time, but will it be faster as well? Fast enough to justify memory overhead?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something other than programming.

Comment: I don't see how this is off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

One **compelling** reason is if you want to support iOS8 extensions with 64-bit operating systems.

From the release notes:

> **Extensions**
>
> Notes
>
> - Extensions need an arm64 slice to run on 64-bit
>     devices. If you try to run the armv7 slice on a 64-bit device it won’t
>     work.
> - Apps need to have an arm64 slice if the bundle contains a
>     framework that both the app and the app extension link against.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/index.html